# Pyplot - show x-axis labels according to y-axis value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 1min 20s long video record of 23.813 FPS. More precisely, I have 1923 frames in which I've been scanning desired features. I've detected some specific behavior via neural network and using chosen metric I calculated a value for each frame.

So, now, I have X-Y values to plot a graph:

```
X: time (each step of size 0,041993869s)
Y: a value measured by neural network
```

In the default state, the plot looks like this:

[image: default plot rendering]

So, I've tried to limit the number of bins in the faith that the bins will be spread over all my values. But they are not. As you can see, only first fifteen x-values are rendered:

```
pyplot.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=15)
```

[image]

But neither one is desired state. The desired state should render the labels of such x-bins with y-value higher than e.g. `1.2`. So, it should look like this:

[image: desired state]

Is possible to achieve such result?

**Code:**

```
# draw plot
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot

test_video_fps = 23.813

df = read_csv('/path/to/csv/file/file.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['anomaly']

df['time'] = [round((i + 1) / test_video_fps, 2) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

axes = df.plot.bar(x='time', y='anomaly', rot='0')
# pyplot.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=15)
# axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

fig = pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 10)
fig.savefig('/path/to/output/plot.png', dpi=100)

# pyplot.show()
```

**Example:**

Simple example with a subset of original data.

```
0.379799
0.383786
0.345488
0.433286
0.469474
0.431993
0.474253
0.418843
0.491070
0.447778
0.384890
0.410994
0.898229
1.872756
2.907009
3.691382
4.685749
4.599612
3.738768
8.043357
7.660785
2.311198
1.956096
2.877326
3.467511
3.896339
4.250552
6.485533
7.452986
7.103761
2.684189
2.516134
1.512196
1.435303
0.852047
0.842551
0.957888
0.983085
0.990608
1.046679
1.082040
1.119655
0.962391
1.263255
1.371034
1.652812
2.160451
2.646674
1.460051
1.163745
0.938030
0.862976
0.734119
0.567076
0.417270
```

Desired plot:

[image: desired plot of the example]

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to generate that plot?

Comment: @WilliamMiller I have added the source code into the original question.

Comment: jus want to comment: that's an odd non standard fps

Comment: You shouldn't have "edit" in your question, especially for something necessary like the source code. SO will maintain a proper version history for you.

Comment: @deadvoid. I've seen enough sensors now to wonder what *is* standard.

Comment: You'll want to use a formatter and locator on your axis. I'll post an answer in a bit

Comment: @deadvoid It is FPS achieved by common webcam connected via USB to my laptop. Video is recorded by Webcamoid on Linux Ubuntu. FPS is variable between all records, and it is dependent on many conditions. Main condition is the performance of my laptop. Another ones are e.g. light conditions and so on.

Comment: @MadPhysicist for frame based, e.g. celluloid, the standard is 24fps. for broadcast/video tapes: 25fps is PAL/SECAM, 29.97fps is NTSC. HD brought 23.89fps. Other source captures most likely derived from those, hence you'll see old mobile or CCTV recordings at 12 or ~14-15fps.

Comment: @deadvoid. Many modern sensors allow you to set your own external clock, which can depend on some other part of your electronics. It can get really weird really fast.

Comment: @Honza. One more thing: how do you intend to handle the cases where many consecutive bins are > 1.2? Your figure shows some grouping, but you should really be specific.

Comment: yeah, for those systems I mentioned the sync clock is within the system standard whether built in or networked. i guess there's a lot more non standardized hardwares out there.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would like to mark only the first bar of group, if it is possible. Interesting is start and end, but the start much more. So the time label should be rendered when the value overlaps the threshold, wait until last overlapped value in the group and render next label together with next overlapped value (I hope my explanation is understandable).

Comment: @MadPhysicist I thought it could be helpful to provide you my datafile, so I have tried to edit my question and there is no possibility to attach CSV file, or is it? Can I provide the datafile another way?

Comment: @Honza. No need, I get the gist well enough. For a really minimal example, you should come up with a dataset with <50 or so samples that illustrates the issue.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok, I've added a simple example data with desired plot (I believe I've calculated time values correctly).

Comment: I posted my answer before you showed the data, but I think you'll find that the concept is transferrable. Thanks for staying responsive and editing necessary info into your question. It's not often that I see people doing that nowadays on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has become a two-part problem, but it is interesting enough that I will answer both.

I will answer this in Matplotlib object oriented notation with numpy data rather than pandas. This will make things easier to explain, and can be easily generalized to pandas.

I will assume that you have the following two data arrays:

```
dt = 0.041993869
x = np.arange(0.0, 15 * dt, dt)
y = np.array([1., 1.1, 1.3, 7.6, 2.4, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0, 1.5, 10.0, 4.5, 3.2, 0.9, 0.7])
```

**Part 1: Identifying the locations where you want labels**

The data can be masked to get the locations of the peaks:

```
mask = y > 1.2
```

Consecutive peaks can be easily eliminated by computing the diff. A diff of a boolean mask will be `True` at the locations where the mask changes sense. You will then have to take every other element to get the locations where it goes from `False` to `True`. The following code will capture all the corner cases where you start with a peak or end in the middle of a peak:

```
d = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(mask))
if mask[d[0]]:  # First diff is end of peak: True to False
    d = np.concatenate(([0], d[1::2] + 1))
else:
    d = d[::2] + 1
```

`d` is now an array indices into `x` and `y` that represent the first element of each run of peaks. You can get the last element by swapping the indices `[1::2]` and `[::2]` in the `if-else` statement, and removing the `+ 1` in both cases.

The locations of the labels are now simply `x[d]`.

**Part 2: Locating and formatting the labels**

For this part, you will need to access Matplotlib's object oriented API via the `Axes` object you are plotting on. You already have this in the pandas form, making the transfer easy. Here is a sample in raw Matplotlib:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot(x, y)
```

Now use the [ticker API](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) to easily set the locations and labels. You actually set the locations directly (not with a `Locator`) since you have a very fixed list of ticks:

```
axes.set_xticks(x[d])
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:0.01g}s'))
```

For the sample data show here, you get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and I am sorry I did not respond immediately. It was too late and I had to sleep, only 4 hours left to go to my office. Thank you for your praise, if there would be more people, who answering what I am asking and demanding additional information, I will always stay responsive like with you. Unfortunately, I was not able to follow your instructions yet, because I was very busy. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you very much again. Bye

Comment: Hi again. So, everything works, when I convert pandas to numpy at the beginning and when I follow your instructions. But when I am using pandas for whole process, I have to call `axes.set_xticks(df.index[d])` instead of `axes.set_xticks(x[d])` and in the final plot I get correct ticks, but the labels are not anomaly values, they are indexes of the column. So I have tried to call `axes.set_xticklabels(df['time'][d])` after `set_xticks`, but nothing changed. The ticks are on correct positions, but with wrong labels. Any idea, please? In the end, I can use your approach with numpy, but... :-)

Comment: @Honza. Have you tried setting the formatter to display your values? It would accept the index as `x` and print the value at that index in the df. You'd probably want a different formatter class though. You might want to ask a different question at this point.

Comment: MadPhysicist, thank you very much again. You were awesome, your advice was very helpful and solved my problem. You as a human, you were amazing, friendly and factual. My last issue I solved again thanks to your advice. I've used the `IndexFormatter`: specifically `axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.IndexFormatter(['{:.1f}s'.format(time) for time in df['time']]))`. Again, thank you very much, everything is working perfectly now, good bye.